# How can I get two slideshows on the same page?

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I am creating a website for an assignment and am trying to add a second slideshow to my page, however, when I do so, it moves my first one and all of the pictures to the section that I'm trying to add to. I have an example of my code below - which shows the java I'm using:

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

and the html I have:

```
main>
    
    <section>       
            
        <div class="flex-container">

            <div class="flex-child">
                
                <!--------------Shine Falls ----------->

                <!-- Slideshow container -->
                <div class="slideshow-container">

                  <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
                  <div class="mySlides fade">
                    <div class="numbertext">1 / 5</div>
                    <img src="Images/Shine Falls/s2.jpg" style="width:100%">
                    <div class="text">Shine Falls entry</div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="mySlides fade">
                    <div class="numbertext">2 / 5</div>
                    <img src="Images/Shine Falls/s3.jpg" style="width:100%">
                    <div class="text">Shine Falls entry</div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="mySlides fade">
                    <div class="numbertext">3 / 5</div>
                    <img src="Images/Shine Falls/s4.jpg" style="width:100%">
                    <div class="text">Shine Falls farm track</div>
                  </div>
                  
                  <div class="mySlides fade">
                    <div class="numbertext">4 / 5</div>
                    <img src="Images/Shine Falls/s5.jpg" style="width:100%">
                    <div class="text">Shine Falls</div>
                  </div>
                  
                  <div class="mySlides fade">
                    <div class="numbertext">5 / 5</div>
                    <img src="Images/Shine Falls/s6.jpg" style="width:100%">
                    <div class="text">Shine Falls base</div>
                  </div>

                  <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
                  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
                  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
                </div>
                <br>

                <!-- The dots/circles -->
                <div style="text-align:center">
                  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
                  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
                  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
                  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
                  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span>
                </div>

                <!---Icons under images -->
                <div class= "icon-display">
                    <a><img  src="Images/Icons/nodogs.png" alt="No Dogs Allowed" /></a>
                    <a><img src="Images/Icons/picnictable.png" alt="Picnic Area" /></a>
                    <a><img src="Images/Icons/toilet.png" alt="Toilets" /></a>
                    <a><img  src="Images/Icons/swimming.png" alt="Swimming Area" /></a>
                    <a><img src="Images/Icons/nowater.png" alt="No Water" /></a>
                    <a><img src="Images/Icons/vehicle.png" alt="All Vehicle Access" /></a>
                </div>
                
                <p>Shine Falls</p>
          
            </div>
          
            <!--------------Maraetotara Falls----------->
          
            <div class="flex-child">
                 ***[** I WANT TO ADD MY SECOND SLIDESHOW HERE **][1]***
                <div>
                    <img src = "Images/Maraetotara Falls/m1.jpg">
                </div>
            
                <div class= "icon-display">
                    <a><img  src="Images/Icons/nodogs.png" alt="No Dogs Allowed" /></a>
                    <a><img src="Images/Icons/picnictable.png" alt="Picnic Area" /></a>
                    <a><img src="Images/Icons/toilet.png" alt="Toilets" /></a>
                    <a><img  src="Images/Icons/swimming.png" alt="Swimming Area" /></a>
                    <a><img src="Images/Icons/nowater.png" alt="No Water" /></a>
                    <a><img src="Images/Icons/vehicle.png" alt="All Vehicle Access" /></a>
                </div>
                
                <p>Maraetotara Falls</p>
                    <p>frjkfsfapkfnaegjbesjglnsjgbsdkgjbsdjfbdakjbgsjdbgsjbssf
                    sdjfbsdgbkdsklgnflkdnglkfdnhgfdklnhgkhngklhgf
                    fndfnf sjkfnshdkghsfhgri... <a href="MaraetotaraFalls.html">Read More</a></p>
                    
            </div>

        </div>

    </section>  
        
</main>
```

I basically want to replicate the slideshow in another section but with different pictures.  I have added a picture of what my website looks like below, to help.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hJzv.jpg  - a link to the photo of my website

Comment: To run *N* of something you need to ensure your selectors don't collide. In order to fix that you need to scope the searches, usually inside a given `#` ID.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to wrap the content (new mySlides divs, next, and prev button) within a div that has a class equal to "slideshow-container"? Similar to how you did it for the Shine Falls section... Currently you just have the flex child with a single div, icon display, and description in it. No slideshow-container to be seen. Am I overlooking somethin?